# How to Play Audio Files using HTML in Android?

Tags: android, html

I need to play audio files using HTML using Android. For example: I have the audio URL file `http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/011/Music/12/14/7f/mzm.ubzkrulq.aac.p.m‌​4a` and need to make it play in a HTML browser. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try it -

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(<http url>);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```